# How to Sort a column Bound to UltraComboEditor which is not a display member

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have an `UltraComboEditor`, The Datasource Table contains 4 columns.
`Code(string)`, `Description(String)`, `Filer(string)`, `createdDate(DateTime)`
UltraComboEditor's valuemember is code and Displaymember is Description.
I would like to display the only Description by sorting CreatedDate by descending.

when I try with below code:
the combo is my UltraComboEditor

```
combo.ValueMember = "Code";
combo.DisplayMember = "Description";
combo.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns["CreatedDate"].SortIndicator = SortIndicator.Descending;
```

it's not displaying description assorted by created date.
Could you let me know how to achieve this?

Comment: are you using UltraCombo or UltraComboEditor. If you are using UltraComboEditor it has no DisplaLayout property. You should use SortStyle to sort the values.

Comment: It's easiest to sort the underlying DataSource and then bind it to your UltraCombo or UltraComboEditor.